# Counting Zeros with Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I'm attempting to answer the question, "Prove that for any positive number $\epsilon$, the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+i} + \sin(z)$ has infinitely many zeros on the strip $|Im(z)|<\epsilon$".

My Work So Far: I know that I want to apply Rouche's Theorem. Assuming I understand Roche's Theorem correctly, I want to think of a function $g(z)$ that has infinitely many zeros in the strip $|Im(z)| < \epsilon$ and then show that $|f(z)-g(z)|$ is less than either $|g(z)|$ or $|f(z)|$. To this end, I thought of $g(z) = sin(z)$ since it has infinitely many zeros in the region of interest, which in of itself seems fairly indicative. However, when I attempt to use this $g(z)$, I end up with $|\frac{1}{z+i}|$, which seems like it can become arbitrarily small for $\epsilon \geq i$. As such, I can't bound this term by either $|g(z)|$ or $|f(z)|$. Am I missing something in my application of Roche's Theorem, or am I perhaps looking at the wrong $g(z)$ to begin with?

To address a more general question for the community, am I perhaps misapplying Rouche's Theorem, or is there perhaps a different way/trick that I should be thinking when addressing Roche's Theorem and problems of a similar nature to this one?

Comment: Note that the strip $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |\mathrm{Im}(z)| < \epsilon_1 \}$ is contained in the strip $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |\mathrm{Im}(z)| < \epsilon_2 \}$ whenever $\epsilon_1 \leq \epsilon_2$. Thus, if you can prove your statement for small $\epsilon$, it would certainly also hold for bigger $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, So it's perfectly fine for me to say that $\epsilon < i$ since if my function $f(z)$ has infinitely many zeros for $|Im(z)|< \epsilon$, then it will also have infinitely many zeros for $|Im(z)| < \delta$ when $\delta > \epsilon$. With that, I can bound that pesky term by $|\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)i}|$. To finish this proof, would I then argue that I can pick a compact subset, $K$ of $|Im(z)| < \epsilon$ s.t $|sin(z)| > 0$ on the boundry of $K$. Thus I have $|f(z)-g(z)| =\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} < f(z)$ on the boundry of $K$, or is that incorrect? @ Adrián Barquero

Comment: What does $\epsilon < i$ mean?  Do you mean $\epsilon < |i|?$

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon < |i|$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the disks of radius $ϵ$ around the roots $z_k=k\pi$ of $\sin z$. For $|k|$ large enough, the term $\frac1{z+i}$ will be a very small perturbation of the sine function which has one simple root inside such a disk.

One can prove for $|z-k\pi|<1$

- $|\sin z|\ge 0.8|z-k\pi|$, 
  \begin{align}\small\text{as for }w=z-k\pi:\qquad
   |\sin w-w|
   &\small\le \tfrac16|w|^3(1+\tfrac1{20}|w|^2+\dots)\\
   &\small\le \frac{\tfrac16|w|^3}{1-\tfrac1{20}|w|^2}\le\frac{10|w|}{57}\le 0.2|w|
  \end{align}
- $|\frac1{z+i}|\le\frac1{|k|\pi-|z-k\pi|-1}<\frac1{|k|\pi-2}$

so if $|z-k\pi|=ϵ$ and $0.8ϵ(|k|\pi-2)>1\iff |k| > \frac1\pi(2+\frac{1.25}ϵ)$ then Rouché guarantees that there is exactly one root of $f(z)$ in $B(k\pi,ϵ)$ and thus infinitely many roots in the strip $|Im(z)|<ϵ$ around the real axis.