# How to find numbers of zeroes of a complex function in a region

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider  $ f\left(z\right)=\sin\left(z\right)+\frac{1}{z+i} $.

How can I find the numbers of zeroes of $ f $ in $$ D=\left\{ z:|\operatorname{Im}\left(z\right)|\leq1,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\pi\left(100+\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq \operatorname{Re}\left(z\right)\leq\pi\left(200+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}  $$

The first thing that I thought of is to use the argument theorem, and claim that the number of zeroes inside this curve is given by $ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\intop_{\gamma}\frac{f'}{f} $

I tried to choose the standard parameterization of straight lines and calculate the 4 integrals, but im seems impossible to calculate.

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $z+i$ does not vanish in $D$ it could be useful to work with the function $(z+i)f(z)$ and try to apply Rouché's theorem to this function, the number fo zeros would be the same.

Comment: @en3trix What if $sinz $ vanish somewhere on this rectangle boundary? Rouche's conditions would not be satisfied, and also - the integral would still be complicated

Comment: $\sin z$ does not vanish on the boundary, you should check it. Also, you don't need to calculate any integral, only verify if $|(z+i)\sin z| > 1$ on $\partial D$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759800/counting-zeros, same function, slightly different task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) can be applied to $f(z)=\sin(z)+\frac{1}{z+i}$ and $g(z) = \sin(z)$. Using
$$
 \sin(x+iy) = \sin(x)\cosh(y) + i \cos(x) \sinh(y)
$$
one gets
$$
 |\sin(x+iy)|^2 = \sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y) = \cosh^2(y) - \cos^2(x) \, .
$$

- For $x= (2k+1/2)\pi$ is $\cos(x) = 0$ so that $|\sin(x+iy)| = |\cosh(y)| \ge 1$.
- For $y = \pm 1$ is $|\sin(x+iy)| \ge |\sinh(y)| = \sinh(1) = (e-1/e)/2 > 1$.

It follows that for all $z=x+iy$ on the boundary of $D$
$$
 |f(z) -g(z)| = \frac{1}{|z+i|} \le \frac 1x < 1 < |g(z)|
$$
so that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in $D$.